# Google auth hanging waiting for response

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

Log of execution:

> inside authorize() function ------------------------
>   inside readAuth2TokensFromFile() function ------------------------
>   Error reading Tokens from a file:./credentials/token.json 
>   inside getNewTokensFromGoogleCLI() function ------------------------
>   Authorize this app by visiting this (Google login) url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=...
>   inside getAnswerOn(question) function ------------------------

...waiting for response from Google CLI...

The issue in this function calling readLineInterface:

```
/**
 * @param {string} query The question to ask.
 */
function getAnswerOn(question) {
  console.log("inside getAnswerOn(question) function ------------------------");
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/readline.html
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    });

    rl.question(question, (answer) => {
      console.log("Answer received succesfully!");
      rl.close();
      process.stdin.destroy();
      resolve(answer);
    });

  })
}
```

Full source code of OAuth2Authorizer.js file:

```
//Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882145/is-there-an-async-await-node-js-google-auth-module
//OAuth2Authorizer with Promises
'use strict'
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

//Go to the Google Cloud Dashboard: APIs and Services/ Credentials panel: 
//https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
//OAuth2 Client Credentials (Other):
const KEY = require("./credentials/oauth2.key.json").web;

/**
* Create a new OAuth2 client with the configured keys.
* https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client
*/
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  KEY.client_id,
  KEY.client_secret,
  KEY.redirect_uris[0]
);

function getOAuth2Client() {
  console.log("inside getOAuth2Client ----------------------------");
  return oauth2Client
}


/**
 * reading Tokens from a file:
 * @param {string} path Path to a JSON file where the tokens is stored in.
 */
function readAuth2TokensFromFile(path) {
  console.log("inside readAuth2TokensFromFile() function ------------------------");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      resolve(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path).toString()));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error reading Tokens from a file:" + path);
      resolve(undefined)
    }
  })
}


/**
 * @param {string} query The question to ask.
 */
function getAnswerOn(question) {
  console.log("inside getAnswerOn(question) function ------------------------");
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/readline.html
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    });

    rl.question(question, (answer) => {
      console.log("Answer received succesfully!");
      rl.close();
      process.stdin.destroy();
      resolve(answer);
    });

  })
}



/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {OAuth2Client} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {string[]} scopes Scopes to get authorization for.
 * @param {string} tokenFilePath Path to a JSON file to store the tokens in.
 * @returns {OAuth2Client} terurns updated oAuth2Client
 */
function getNewTokensFromGoogleCLI(oAuth2Client, scopes, tokenFilePath) {
  console.log("inside getNewTokensFromGoogleCLI() function ------------------------");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: scopes,
    });

    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this (Google login) url: ', authUrl);

    getAnswerOn("Enter the long code from that page here:").then(answer => {
      try {
        console.log("trying to get new token (before getToken) ------------------")
        oAuth2Client.getToken(answer, (err, tokens) => {
          if (!err) {
            // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            resolve(oauth2Client) //return updated oauth2Client <-----------------------------
            try {
              // Store the token to disk for later program executions
              fs.writeFileSync(tokenFilePath, JSON.stringify(tokens));
              console.log('Token stored to', tokenFilePath);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error while storing tokens in a file", error);
              reject(new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message));
            }
          } else {
            console.error('Error in oAuth2Client.getToken() function', err);
            reject(new functions.https.HttpsError(err.code, err.message));
          }
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', error);
        reject(new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message));
      }
    })
  })
}


function authorize(key, scopes, tokenPath) {
  console.log("inside authorize() function ------------------------");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      let REQ_SCOPES = scopes;
      if (Array.isArray(scopes)) {
        REQ_SCOPES = scopes.join(" "); //convert an array to the string  
      }

      /*
      * Create a new OAuth2 client with the configured keys.
      * https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client
      */
      const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        key.client_id,
        key.client_secret,
        key.redirect_uris[0]
      );

      readAuth2TokensFromFile(tokenPath).then(tokens => {
        if (tokens) {
          oauth2Client.setCredentials(auth2tokensTokens);
          resolve(oauth2Client);
        } else {
          getNewTokensFromGoogleCLI(oauth2Client, REQ_SCOPES, tokenPath).then(updatedOAauth2Client => {
            resolve(updatedOAauth2Client)
          })
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while getting a new oauth2Client from key: ', error);
      reject(new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message));
    }
  })
}

//Use: const { authorize } = require('./OAuth2Authorizer.js');
exports.authorize = authorize;
```

Comment: did you place the url in the browser window and copy the authorization code back into your application?

Comment: No I didn't. Is it requested only once?

Comment: Thats depends upon how you have your code setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Oauth2 works your application needs to request permission of a user to access their data.  To do that we show them a consent form.   Your script is telling you that

```
console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this (Google login) url: ', authUrl);
getAnswerOn("Enter the long code from that page here:").then(answer => {
```

As seen here

> Authorize this app by visiting this (Google login) url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=...

Take the full URL it gives you.  Put it in a web browser consent to the access it will give you an authorization code.   Take this code back and place it in your application where it is waiting for it.

Your application isnt hanging its waiting for you to respond to its request.

Comment: Yes I opened the url provided in the Browser:
It looks like: __/auth/handler?code=4/xxxxx-xxxxxx8&scope=https://mail.google.com/%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send - Do I need to save all text after "code=" in the file?

Comment: the authorization code can only be used once there is no need to save it.

Comment: YOur code apears to be storing the refresh token to the file   fs.writeFileSync(tokenFilePath, JSON.stringify(tokens));   It would be a good idea to try to understand your code rather than just copying it from someplace and running it.

Comment: I understand the code. And I modified this code in order it use Promises. But the function finishes with an error : Function execution took 500002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout' and Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable'... it didn't save the code

Comment: Thats a diffrent error try and figuer it out if not post a new question.

Comment: Sorry @DalmTo may I ask you the last question: is OAuth2 for Frontend use only?

Comment: In a way yes Oauth2 will require that a user authcate your code at least once you can then save the refresh token to use to request a new access token.    Service accounts are most often used for server to server communication but its not supported by all APIS

Comment: Golden words: "Service accounts are most often used for server to server communication but its not supported by all APIS"